# add data at 0th index of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to add more data at 0th index of my array. There is already an array stored at 0th index of my array. Here is the line of code where data is stored at 0th index of my array.

```
    if ([[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"IsValidUser"]) {
        [albumURLArray addObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"]];
    }
```

Here, albumURLArray is a NSMutableArray and at its 0th index, the object will be stored. Now, I want to add more URL at 0th index of the same array. So, How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[How to add object at first index of NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854576/how-to-add-object-at-first-index-of-nsarray)  In this question's answer, the data is added at new index in the NSMutableArray while what I want is I want to add new data at 0th index of that array. So, my requirement is different then this question.

Comment: the method is insertObject:atIndex:

Comment: I think your `albumURLArray` is actually a dictionary. The function you are using to store the data is not supported on arrays and is a dictionary function.

Comment: I have already tried insetObject:atIndex: method but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add object at first index of NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854576/how-to-add-object-at-first-index-of-nsarray)

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala I have edited my question once again to explain my problem in detail.

Comment: So you need to replace the data at 0th index?

Comment: If you want to add a new object at first index then this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854820/2099097

Comment: I do not want to replace the data at 0th index. I want to add more data at the 0th index. The previous data should remain same and the new data should be added.

Answer (score 2):

```
if([albumURLArray count]>0)
    {
       [albumURLArray removeAllObjects];
       [albumURLArray addObject:[albumDetailsResponse  valueForKey:@"data"]];

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create one array and use that array as the 0th Index of Your `albumURLArray`

For e.g

```
NSMutableArray *arrtemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrtemp addObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"]];
[arrtemp addObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"URL"]];


[albumURLArray addObject:arrtemp];
```

To get the URL,

```
Use [[albumURLArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
[albumURLArray insertObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"] atIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[albumURLArray insertObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"] atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an object to the front of the array, use 0 as the index:

```
[albumURLArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use-

```
[albumURLArray insertObject:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"] atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead adding array to 0th Index. Add a NSMutableDictionary. And add one key for response data and an NSArray for URL's.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dataDictionary setValue:[albumDetailsResponse valueForKey:@"data"] forKey:@"data"];

NSMutableArray * urlArray = @[[NSURl urlWithString:@"http://someurl.com"], [NSURl urlWithString:@"http://someurl1.com"]];

dataDictionary setValue:urlArray forKey:@"URLS"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> have already tried `insetObject:atIndex:` method but it didn't work.

The only three reasons it wouldn't work:

- `NSMutableArray` isn't initialized. (i.e. `albumURLArray = [@[] mutableCopy];`or `albumURLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`)
- The index isn't correct (i.e. no item added yet but index 1 instead 0 used.)
- The array is a plain `NSArray`

Comment: 1. If I'll initialize array then I will lost all the data at 0th index, which I do not want to do. 2. I want to add data after the last index and the data is contained at the 0th index of my array. 3. I have already mentioned that my array is not a simple one but it is a mutable array.

Comment: if it wasn't initialised before, there is no data.